# How to check if in arrays column all numbers are negative?

Tags: c++

I created an array of A[rows][columns] random numbers between 100 and -100
saved it in txt file
Now i have to check if all numbers are negative in column and if so save column number in array C[x];

```
    int main()
{
    ofstream out("masyvas.txt");
    srand(time(0));
    int n=rand() % (31 - 10) + 10; // eilutes
    int m=rand() % (31 - 10) + 10; // stulepliai

    int A[n][m];

  for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    for(int j=0; j<m; j++)
            A[i][j]=rand()%100 + (rand()%100 *(-1)) ;
 for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
  {
      for(int j=0; j<m; j++)
            out<<setw(5)<<A[i][j]<<" ";
      out<<endl;
  }
  out.close();
 //------------------------------------------
    return 0;
}
```

so above everything is ok but

```
     ofstream rez("rez.txt");
 for(int i=0; i < m;i++)
 {
     for(int j=0; j< n;j++) {
        if(A[i][j]<0){
                rez << i <<" - column" << j << "- row"<< endl;
        }
     }
 }
    cout << n << endl << m << endl;
    rez.close();
```

first i wanted to print into txt file if it finds negative numbers correctly but i get some nonsense
and i have no clue what to do im stuck for half an hour trying to do different things

Comment: Did you try to debug your program? Do you think "i get some nonsense" is a sufficient description of the program's behaviour? Please create a [mcve].

Comment: on rez txt file. j - row should print a row number that has a negative number, but it doesnt it prints some of the rows numbers but thouse rows doenst have a negative number so i dont understand whats the problem here

Comment: So, did you step through the code and see why is the `rez <<` line triggered?

Comment: Variable length array `int A[n][m];` is not standard C++. You should use `std::vector`

Answer (score 2):

First thing, don't panic, read your code and actually know what it is doing.

To check if all numbers in a column are negative, you need to loop over an entire column first while having something, preferably a boolean, to tell you if any of them is not negative.

For example: create a flag that defaults to true.

```
bool allNegative = true;
for ( int i =0; i < (sizeof(matrix[0])/sizeof(int)); i++)
{
  if(matrix[i][0] > 0) allNegative = false; // change the flag to indicate that it is not all negative
}
```

Then what you want to do is if the flag is still true, loop that column again to just copy and paste all this code for each row to output that column to a txt file.

```
out<<setw(5)<<A[i][j]<<" ";
out<<endl;
```

EDIT: thanks to comment, I have changed the syntax error.

Comment: How can such a bad and none compilable answer get 2 upvotes and an acceptance. Strange . . .

Comment: @ArminMontigny You are right, I messed up between vector and array. I have edited the answer. It should be working for OP's code now.